# Using custom event(s) in Dialogflow to invoke an event via the detect intent API

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am sending a request to the /query per the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events) with parameter names and parameter values. However I can not get any of the parameter slots to fill within the intent itself.

Example Payload:

```
{
        "contexts": ["member"],
            "event": {
                    "name": "memberLookup",
                    "parameters": {
                            "baseState": "az",
                            "occurrenceState": "ny"
                    },
                    "languageCode": "en-US"
            },
    "lang": "en",
    "sessionId": "1"
```

}

I am referencing in my parameters per the docs, i.e. `#memberLookup.baseState`

Response Snippet

```
    "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "memberLookup",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": true,
    "parameters": {
        "baseState": "",
        "occurrenceState": ""
    },
```

Has anyone gotten this functionality to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

V1 formatting is slightly different. `Parameters` in the body should be `data`, then the parameters will be filled. Thanks Dialogflow for reaching out and clearing this up for me.

```
{
    "contexts": ["member"],
        "event": {
                "name": "memberLookup",
                "data": {
                        "baseState": "az",
                        "occurrenceState": "ny"
                },
                "languageCode": "en-US"
        },
"lang": "en",
"sessionId": "1"
}
```

New Result:

```
"result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "memberLookup",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": true,
    "parameters": {
        "baseState": "az",
        "occurrenceState": "ny",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really work for me. When I replace word `parameters` to `data` I received correct answer with necessary parameters:

```
[{'name': 'itbooking-vcs_error-followup', 'parameters': {'room_type.original': 
'', 'description.original': 'test', 'room_number.original': '', 'description':
 'test', 'room_number': '10.12', 'branch': 'headquarter', 'branch.original': '',
 'room_type': 'meeting_room'}, 'lifespan': 1}]
```